# How to back out of a website development job that's way out of my league

Tags: web-applications, freelancing, laravel

**TLDR: project scope has crept beyond my capabilities and I need an early exit strategy (in both parties' best interest)**

Early last year I took on a gig to develop a web application for a financial advisor. The client had built a mega Excel spreadsheet over a decade of consulting. The client had a vision to automate as many processes as possible using the application (deprecating the spreadsheet), and to ultimately provide a self-service feature using a tiered system.

We both knew scoping the work in detail would be a mammoth task, so we agreed to make a start based on what we knew at the time (a huge mistake I learned from this engagement), and we would make changes as we went along (while charging a set hourly rate).

More than 1 year later and hundreds of hours of effort, the scope has grown to a point where I can no longer cope with *or* have the qualifications/knowledge to deal with. I'm not afraid to admit that this project is way beyond my league.

The client isn't concerned with the scope creep or the costs they're incurring, but I know I'm not going to be able to deliver a good, working product. I can feel the weight of this burden all the time. I'm very grateful for the opportunity the client has provided me, but for my own mental health's sake I need an early exit strategy.

I've googled around for ideas but I couldn't find anything useful. Most results were from the client's perspective. Also did the obligatory search on Stack Exchange.

To make the handover as smooth as possible I presume I'll need the following:

- **Find a developer to take on the job**
- Ensure all documentation is complete
- Offer *x* hours of my time, free of charge, to answer any queries post-transition
- Provide all project files to new developer

Am I missing anything? Where can I search for candidates?

Comment: Thanks @gnat, that provides some great insight, particularly with knowledge transfer.